# Submit button for multiple choice without using radio button

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, button

I had a problem when I want to auto submit my choices using codeigniter. My return values into database are ID (integer), status (enum ('masuk','istirahat','kembali','pulang')), waktu (datetime). I want variable 'waktu' is my current datetime if user select one from 'status' button.

Here is my code in views folder:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form Tambah Presensi</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Form Tambah Data Presensi</h1>
    <hr>
    <!-- Menampilkan Error jika validasi tidak valid -->
    <div style="color: red;"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>
    <?php echo form_open("presensi/tambah"); ?>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="input_id" value="<?php echo set_value('input_id'); ?>"></td>
        </tr><br><br>
        <tr>
          <td>Status:</td><br>
          <input type="submit" id="input_status" name="input_status" value="masuk">
          <label for="masuk"></label><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <input type="submit" id="input_status" name="input_status" value="istirahat">
          <label for="istirahat"></label><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <input type="submit" id="input_status" name="input_status" value="kembali">
          <label for="kembali"></label><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <input type="submit" id="input_status" name="input_status" value="pulang">
          <label for="pulang"></label><br><br>
        </tr>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

My code in models folder:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class PresensiModel extends CI_Model {
  
  // Fungsi untuk validasi form tambah dan ubah
  public function validation($mode){
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); // Load library form_validation untuk proses validasinya
    
    // Tambahkan if apakah $mode save atau update
    if($mode == "save")
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('input_id', 'id', 'required|numeric|max_length[11]');
    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('input_status', 'status');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('input_waktu', 'waktu', 'required');
      
    if($this->form_validation->run()) // Jika validasi benar
      return TRUE; // Maka kembalikan hasilnya dengan TRUE
    else // Jika ada data yang tidak sesuai validasi
      return FALSE; // Maka kembalikan hasilnya dengan FALSE
  }
  
  // Fungsi untuk melakukan simpan data ke tabel presensi
  public function save(){
    $data = array(
      "id" => $this->input->post('input_id'),
      "status" => $this->input->post('input_status'),
      "waktu" => $this->input->post('input_waktu')
    );
    
    $this->db->insert('presensi', $data); // Untuk mengeksekusi perintah insert data
  }
}
```

My code in controllers folder:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Presensi extends CI_Controller {
  
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    
    $this->load->model('PresensiModel'); // Load PresensiModel ke controller ini
  }
  
  public function index(){
    $data['presensi'] = $this->PresensiModel->view();
    $this->load->view('presensi/form_tambah', $data);
  }
  
  public function tambah(){
    if($this->input->post('submit')){ // Jika user mengklik tombol submit yang ada di form
      if($this->PresensiModel->validation("save")){ // Jika validasi sukses atau hasil validasi adalah TRUE
        $this->PresensiModel->save(); // Panggil fungsi save() yang ada di SiswaModel.php
        redirect('presensi');
      }
    }
    
    $this->load->view('presensi/form_tambah');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you need to change at 2 places `validation()` and `save()`

In `validation()` function we want to make it optional if user selected any status because we will generate waktu on server, so change

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('input_waktu', 'waktu', 'required');
```

To

```
if(empty( $this->input->post('input_status') ) )
$this->form_validation->set_rules('input_waktu', 'waktu', 'required');
```

Meaning if user haven't selected any status then waktu is mandatory otherwise (by default) it will be optional

---

Then in `save()` function, do a check like this

```
$data = array(
  "id" => $this->input->post('input_id'),
  "status" => $this->input->post('input_status'),
  "waktu" => empty($this->input->post('input_status'))? $this->input->post('input_waktu'): date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

It means use use the value of user provided waktu if status is not selected but if user has selected status then use the server current datetime